# Big Data convert to "transactions" from arules package

Tags: r, transactions, bigdata, apriori

The arules package in R uses the class 'transactions'. So in order to use the function `apriori()` I need to convert my existing data. I've got a Matrix with 2 columns and roughly 1.6mm rows and tried to convert the data like this:

```
transaction_data <- as(split(original_data[,"id"], original_data[,"type"]), "transactions")
```

where original_data is my data matrix. Because of the amount of data I used the largest AWS Amazon machine with 64gb RAM. After a while I get

> resulting vector exceeds vector length limit in 'AnswerType'

The Memory Usage of the machine was still 'only' at 60%. Is this a R-based limitation? Is there any way to work around this other than using sampling? When only using 1/4 of the data the transformation worked fine.

Edit: As pointed out, one of the variables was a factor instead of character. After changing the transformation was processed quickly and correct.

Comment: I played around with it a bit more, and when I reduce the amount of Data by a bit, i get the error
`Error in unique.default(...) length 547601298 is too large for hashing`
Apparently some function `MKsetup()` in the System code of R, in the file unique.c prevents vectors from exceeding a certain length.

Comment: Can you post the results of `str(original_data)`?  It would be good to know if there is some issue arising in the data.

Comment: Can you generate a fake but a representative example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your problem is arising because one of the functions uses integers (rather than, say, floats) to index values.  In any case, the size isn't too big, so this is surprising.  Maybe the data has some other issue, such as characters as factors?

In general, though, I'd really recommend using memory mapped files, via `bigmemory`, which you can also split and process via `bigsplit` or `mwhich`.  If offloading the data works for you, then you can also use a much smaller instance size and save $$.  :)

Comment: You where right, one of the variables was a factor instead of a char. I will look into the `bigmemory` package, thanks for the advice